# Testing ejabberd with Tsung

Tags: ejabberd, tsung

I have a running ejabberd server, how can I load-test it? I tried to use Tsung, but none of found in Google solutions didn't help.

I need to do the following:

1. Pick a bunch of usernames and passwords from file
2. Make them all authenticate and simultaneously send messages, one user to another.
3. It would be great if the solution scales well (I need to test my server for up to 100k online users)

How to do this with Tsung? Are there working solutions? Maybe, there is something better than Tsung?

Thank you.